# Paginate loaded relation with Laravel API resources

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Hi I am loading a relation on an API resource in laravel 5.6:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return new YardResource(Yard::find($id)->with('inspections')->paginate(1));
}
```

YardResource

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'maf_id' => $this->maf_id,
            'street' => $this->street,
            'suburb' => $this->suburb,
            'city' => $this->city,
            'country' => $this->country,
            'lat' => $this->lat,
            'long' => $this->long,
            'landowner_name' => $this->landowner_name,
            'landowner_phone' => $this->landowner_phone,
            'landowner_phone2' => $this->landowner_phone2,
            'landowner_mobile' => $this->landowner_mobile,
            'landowner_mobile2' => $this->landowner_mobile2,
            'landowner_email' => $this->landowner_email,
            'landowner_street' => $this->landowner_street,
            'landowner_suburb' => $this->landowner_suburb,
            'landowner_city' => $this->landowner_city,
            'landowner_country' => $this->landowner_country,
            'landowner_postcode' => $this->landowner_postcode,
            'acquired_at' => $this->acquired_at,
            'quarantined' => $this->quarantined,
            'archived' => $this->archived,
            'latest_inspection' => new Inspection($this->latestInspection),
            'inspections' => InspectionResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('inspections')),
            'tasks' => TaskResource::collection($this->tasks->where('completed', false)), // Get active tasks
            'feedings' => FeedResource::collection($this->feeds),
            'diseases' => DiseaseResource::collection($this->diseases),
            'treatments' => TreatmentResource::collection($this->activeTreatments), // between dates
            'yard_events' => YardEventResource::collection($this->yardEvents),
        ];
    }
```

I am wanting to paginate the 'inspections' relation but am having no luck.

Have this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin sorry just added that

Comment: change paginate(1) with first()

Comment: and what is YardResource ?

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin first() will grab the first item though, I am wanting to be able to paginate the results. Have added the YardResource

Comment: Why are you using a pagination when you're passing the id?

Answer (score 0):

paginate works on collections , it seems that your toArray method cant change paginated results so change the normal collections to your desired array and then change your array to collection and finally paginate it.
I think you can do sth like this

```
$resultArray = new YardResource(Yard::find($id)->with('inspections')); // if your toArray method supports any size of objects 
$resultCollecttion = collect($resultArray);
return $resultCollection->paginate(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that this problem is not the resource layer itself, but a relational level failure of the entities in the models. Verify that the inspector model is related to Yard correctly.

If that's OK, then test the resource's response without adding the relationship

`return new YardResource(Yard::find($id)->paginate(1));`

Then you can discard exactly where the problem is coming from